# Как в activity по результату ответа на вопрос Закрыть Да/Нет отказаться от закрытия?

Tags: java, android, activity

Здравствуйте, подскажите пожалуйста как в activity по результату ответа на вопрос "Закрыть Да/Нет" отказаться от закрытия activity?

Код в активности

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    backBeginActivity();
}

protected void backBeginActivity() {
        String title = "Закрыть активность?";
        String message = "Закрыть?";
        String buttonYES = "Да";
        String buttonNO = "Нет";

        AlertDialog.Builder ad = new     AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivitySelectTaxi.this);
        ad.setTitle(title);  // заголовок
        ad.setMessage(message); // сообщение
        ad.setPositiveButton(buttonYES, new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int arg1) {
                finish(); //Закрыли
            }
        });
        ad.setNegativeButton(buttonNO, new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int arg1) {
                //А как не закрывать??? Что написать или как это делается?
            }
        });
        ad.setCancelable(true);
        ad.setOnCancelListener(new OnCancelListener() {
            public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {

            }
        });
        ad.show();
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public void onBackPressed() {
    //super.onBackPressed();    вот это отсюда убираем
    backBeginActivity(); 
}
```

Comment: То есть нужно закомментировать вызов конструктора суперкласса, я правильно понял?

Comment: @Flippy не конструктора, а метода `onBackPressed()`. Собственно в оригинальном методе перебирается стек activity либо производится выход, если стек пуст

Comment: Спасибо, понял )

Answer (score 0):

Просто закройте диалог, вам в параметрах приходит его инстанс. dialog.dismiss()

Comment: В onBackPressed() это не отменит закрытие, колбэк срабатывает при нажатии кнопки "назад" и процесс "уже пошел"